# Docker couldn't connect to the database running on the same server

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker images 1) for couchdb and 2) a web application. The web application couldnt able to talk to the couchdb which is running on the same machine.

When I access couchdb directly it is working http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#database/
http://0.0.0.0:5984/_utils/#database/

What am I missing any pointers?

```
| Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:5984 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
hashgraph_1  |  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
```

my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  hashgraph:
    build: "./"
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "51200-51299:51200-51299"
  couchdb:
    image: couchdb:2.1
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
```

Output of docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                   NAMES
cc7e37cd6260        hashgraphexperiments_hashgraph   "java -jar swirlds.j…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   50200-50299/tcp, 0.0.0.0:51200-51299->51200-51299/tcp   hashgraphexperiments_hashgraph_1
9f4767b36aea        couchdb:2.1                      "tini -- /docker-ent…"   2 hours ago          Up About a minute   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp              hashgraphexperiments_couchdb_1
```

Comment: you are trying to connect the couchdb running in port : 5984 of the 
 host machine. have you mapped the webapplication port to this as well?

Comment: yes I did, In the web application my configuration to connect to couchdb is { "key": "protocol", "value": "http"}, { "key": "host", "value": "couchdb"},

Comment: show the docker compose file or how you run it.

Comment: Do "docker ps" and show the state of both dockers

Comment: Hi, I added the docker ps output. still have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**depends_on**: it just wait to the other container to be started.

Whenever you want to call the `couchdb` from the `hashgraph` container code, you need to use `couchdb:5984` instead of `localhost:5984`

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

---

You can also explicitly use the `links` entry instead of `depends_on`.

The description of links is

> **links**: Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service name and a link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name.

Links also express dependency between services in the same way as depends_on, so they determine the order of service startup.

```
version: "3"
services:
  hashgraph:
    build: .
    links:
      - couchdb:couchdb
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "51200-51299:51200-51299"
  couchdb:
    image: couchdb:2.1
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
```

Comment: This doesn't work: http://couchdb:5984/_utils/, I tried accessing with the browser. With http://localhost:5984/_utils/ I am seeing the couchdb page whereas with the other getting "couchdb’s server IP address could not be found."

Comment: This http://couchdb:5984/_utils  is to call the couchdb FROM THE hashgraph container not from your local machine

Comment: can you post you docker ps console data?

Comment: @Minisha The `localhost` being used by the web application is **that** web app container. In that code, you need to connect to a remote server. Therefore, the `links` setup in compose. Though, the link is actually not needed, as pointed out here. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Correct @cricket_007 You can always call other service by his service name

Comment: Then is there a reason to put `couchdb:couchdb` in the answer other than just to show it's possible?

Comment: Just to make it more "clear" and tho show the posibility of using an alias, even thougth in this example is the same as the service.

Comment: @jonhid added the docker ps to the question

Comment: As we said before "Whenever you want to call the couchdb from the hashgraph container code, you need to use couchdb:5984 instead of localhost:5984"